# "NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'" when initializing auth() in flutter for web

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I'm trying to implement sign-in function with Firebase Authentication in Flutter for Web app.
I can already use Firestore to store/ extract data in the same app without signing-in.

When executing the app, it shows the error "NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'"

I think the error is caused by calling `auth()` method.

Can you please advise how I should fix it?
Or, is Firebase Authentication not supported Flutter for web yet??

Imported firebase.dart.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase

`import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';`

Initialized an object with auth() and called sign-in method from the parameter.

```
final Auth _auth = auth();

Future<UserCredential> signIn(String email, String password) async {
  final UserCredential user = await _auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  return user;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your app to see if the value that you're passing to _auth is indeed null? Are you sure you're connected with your app to the database, i.e: no mistakes in the app_name,  having google-services.json in the app folder.

Comment: Ryk, thanks for the comment.  Actually it's not possible for me to confirm whether _auth is indeed null or not, because the app is crashed when just calling `auth()`... Is there any way to confirm it?
Yes, I can fetch and put data with firestore from the app. I don't use google-services.json nor GoogleService-Info.plist, because the app is for web. Instead of that, I call `initializeApp()`.
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initialize-app)

Comment: do you use a package from pub? if you use package firebase from pub, you should also insert firebase-app.js to your page. I don't use flutter for web, so I don't know where to place the script on your app.

Comment: Oon, thank you. Yes, I use a package from pub and also insert firebase-app.js to my index.html. `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>`

Comment: FYI. I also found a discussion in Reddit below. But I cannot find the difference between my code and this code... https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/ccqgz0/flutter_web_firebase_authentication/

Answer (score 38):

You need include this in your index.html file too:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This can be the solution. I cannot try right now, but will try.

Comment: This provides me a fix, and after insert this row and make my app working i just read the previous lines and there is a hint, which comes from the Firebase setting steps

`<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->`

Comment: Yes. Fixed the issue for me too.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to refresh the cache, reload/hot reload dart with R is not enough, so go on chrome and press CTRL+SHIFT+R at the same time to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not calling the function, in this case: `authStateChanges`, in your index.html file. In addition to adding the script: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>`, you also need to add `import { authStateChanges } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js";` to your Firebase SDK imports section (`<script type="module">`...).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have also been in my situation. I realized I added this line
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>`  twice so I deleted one, saved, and run `flutter clean`.