# Flutter Web App, Firebase.auth not working. Tried to call a non-function, such as null. 'dart.global.firebase.auth'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am trying to implement a simple Flutter Web App, with Firebase Auth.

I am getting the error `NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'`.

I have looked at other posts, such as ["NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'" when initializing auth() in flutter for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114754/nosuchmethoderror-tried-to-call-a-non-function-such-as-null-dart-global-fir) and [Flutter web: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242045/flutter-web-tried-to-call-a-non-function-such-as-null-dart-global-firebase-s).

Both suggest the same solution: add firebase-auth.js to `index.html`. I already did it. This is how my `index.html` file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="my_app">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>my_app</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  
  <!-- Firebase Configuration-->
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>  -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-database.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      //my info
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <!-- End of Firebase Configuration-->
  
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I placed this

```
<!-- Firebase Configuration-->
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>  -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-database.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      //my info
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <!-- End of Firebase Configuration-->
```

In the wrong place.

It should be inside the `<head>` tag.

Side note, I had this `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>` twice, so I deleted the one below.

Finally, thanks to David Iglesias for his answer here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2860#issuecomment-651313186.