# NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

New to Flutter - I suspect there is something very simple I've missed as I try to set up Firebase Auth.

Been canvasing solutions online. Most ask that you double check firebase-auth.js is correctly included in the index.html file. This is done, index.html file below.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628843/flutter-web-app-firebase-auth-not-working-tried-to-call-a-non-function-such-a) and this [post](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2860) indicate that this issue can be addressed by moving my firebase configuration into the head section in the index.html file. Not sure why this is the case, but tried and didn't see any change.

my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter application.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="test_auth">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>test_auth</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Firebase Configuration-->
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
        //my deets
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
      firebase.auth();
      </script>
  <!-- End of Firebase Configuration-->

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

my pubspec.yaml dependancies:

```js
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
```

```
    flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-6.0.pre.170, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 1.21.0-6.0.pre.170 at /Users/olisno/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 4c7fae93aa (6 hours ago), 2020-08-04 10:44:43 -0700
    • Engine revision 033dd45607
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-2.0.dev 0f0e04ec3a)

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/olisno/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • 7F1F5A6D-F82D-46FB-B71B-371887713467 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-6 (simulator)
    • Web Server (web)                    • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)                        • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105

• No issues found!
```

Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I updated the major version only for the version of `firebase_auth` and solved it.

The major version of _core remains 1, but the major version of _auth seems to be updated relatively often.

Changed `firebase_auth: ^1.0.1` to `firebase_auth: ^3.0.1` in `pubspec.yaml`. It seems that you don't need to add the CDN link in `web/index.html`. The pub package will automatically generate the inside of the head tag.