# NoSuchMethodError: 'dart.global.firebase.auth' in the Flutter Chat App

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was creating this Chat App and after implementing the search function I encountered this ***NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'*** problem.

So basically now when I sign up the email and username doesn't get uploaded to firebase auth and Cloud Firestore, which earlier used to happen I think I did some mistake in the *search.dart* file which seems weird to me.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intro/helper/constants.dart';
import 'package:intro/services/database.dart';
import 'package:intro/widgets/widgets.dart';

import 'conversation_screen.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;

  Widget searchList() {
    return searchSnapshot != null
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return searchTile(
                searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"],
                searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
              );
            })
        : Container();
  }

  initiateSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = val;
      });
    });
  }

  createChatroomAndStartConversation({String userName}) {
    String chatRoomId = getChatRoomId(userName, Constants.myName);

    List<String> users = [userName, Constants.myName];
    Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomMap = {
      "users": users,
      "chatroomid": chatRoomId
    };
    DatabaseMethods().createChatRoom(chatRoomId, chatRoomMap);
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ConversationScreen(),
        ));
  }

  Widget searchTile(String userName, String userEmail) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(userName, style: mediumTextStyle()),
              Text(userEmail, style: mediumTextStyle())
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              createChatroomAndStartConversation(userName: userName);
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 6),
              child: Text(
                "Message",
                style: mediumTextStyle(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarMain(context),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Color(0x54FFFFFF),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
              child: Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: searchTextEditingController,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search Username",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white54,
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    initiateSearch();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      height: 35,
                      width: 35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                            const Color(0x36FFFFFF),
                            const Color(0x0FFFFFFF)
                          ]),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                )
              ]),
            ),
            searchList()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

getChatRoomId(String a, String b) {
  if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
    return "$b\_$a";
  } else {
    return "$a\_$b";
  }
}
```

and just in case there is an error with the *signUp.dart* file here it is.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intro/helper/helperfunctions.dart';
import 'package:intro/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:intro/services/database.dart';
import 'package:intro/widgets/widgets.dart';

import 'chatRoomsScreen.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggle;
  SignUp(this.toggle);
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  AuthMethods authMethods = new AuthMethods();
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController userNameTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  signMeUP() {
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      Map<String, String> userInfoMap = {
        "name": userNameTextEditingController.text,
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text,
      };

      HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(
          emailTextEditingController.text);
      HelperFunctions.saveUserNameSharedPreference(
          userNameTextEditingController.text);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      authMethods
          .signUpwithemailandpassword(emailTextEditingController.text,
              passwordTextEditingController.text)
          .then((value) {
        // print("$value.uid");

        databaseMethods.uploadUserInfo(userInfoMap);
        HelperFunctions.saveUserLoggedInSharedPreference(true);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatRoom()));
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarMain(context),
      body: isLoading
          ? Container(
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 60,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Form(
                        key: formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              validator: (val) {
                                return val.isEmpty || val.length < 2
                                    ? "Invalid Username (Needs to be more than 2 characters)"
                                    : null;
                              },
                              controller: userNameTextEditingController,
                              style: simpleTextStyle(),
                              decoration: textfieldInputDecoration("username"),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              validator: (val) {
                                return RegExp(
                                            r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                                        .hasMatch(val)
                                    ? null
                                    : "Enter correct email";
                              },
                              controller: emailTextEditingController,
                              style: simpleTextStyle(),
                              decoration: textfieldInputDecoration("email"),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              validator: (val) {
                                return val.length < 6
                                    ? "Please provide with 6+ character"
                                    : null;
                              },
                              controller: passwordTextEditingController,
                              style: simpleTextStyle(),
                              decoration: textfieldInputDecoration("password"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Container(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                          child: Text(
                            "Forgot Password?",
                            style: simpleTextStyle(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          signMeUP();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                const Color(0xff007EF4),
                                const Color(0xff2A75BC)
                              ]),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          child: Text("Sign Up", style: mediumTextStyle()),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        child: Text("Sign Up with Google",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Already have an account? ",
                            style: mediumTextStyle(),
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              widget.toggle();
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                              child: Text(
                                "Sign in now",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

And if there is any file anyone of you want: [GitHub: Chat App](https://github.com/pranjalchaplot/ChatApp)

Comment: To help out, I've found a link here in a similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628843/flutter-web-app-firebase-auth-not-working-tried-to-call-a-non-function-such-a

Answer (score -1):

Because you Haven't initialize the method

Comment: can you explain a bit more buddy? I am new to flutter so I don't get it completely..